# ListView getChildrenCount is 0

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview, android-adapter

I'm developing a `NavigationDrawer` with `ListView`. I have a `ArrayList<Objetct X>` to the items for the `ListView`

A parcial code:

```
private ListView mDrawerList;
private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;
private NavDrawerListAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    //Get View of ListView
    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);

    //Generate the Objects and add to ArrayList
    navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();
    for (int i = 0; i < navMenuTitles.length; i++) {
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[i], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(i, -1)));
    }

    ...

    adapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(this, navDrawerItems);
    System.out.println("ArrayList_size: "+navDrawerItems.size());
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);
    System.out.println("ListView_child_1:"+mDrawerList.getChildCount());

    ...
}

@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    ...

    if(centroComercial==null){
        System.out.println("ListView_child_2: "+mDrawerList.getChildCount());
        ((TextView) mDrawerList.getChildAt(0).findViewById(R.id.title)).setTextColor(this.getResources().getColor(R.color.list_item_title_unselected));
        ((ImageView) mDrawerList.getChildAt(0).findViewById(R.id.icon)).setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_home_des);
    }else{
        ((TextView) mDrawerList.getChildAt(0).findViewById(R.id.title)).setTextColor(this.getResources().getColor(R.color.list_item_title));
        ((ImageView) mDrawerList.getChildAt(0).findViewById(R.id.icon)).setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_home);
    }

}
```

When I launch the app fist time, all works, and this is the output:

```
ArrayList_size: 7
ListView_child_1: 0
ListView_child_2: 7
```

The array list contains all items. `ListView_child_1: 0` possibly an early call, and returns 0, but it isn't a problem. After, in `onPrepareOptionsMenu`, this call return 7
All right.

But when I rotate the screen, the activity is recreated, and build new `ArrayList`, and new `ListView`, but now when `getChildCount()` is called, this returns 0 all times.
This is the output:

```
ArrayList_size: 7
ListView_child_1: 0
ListView_child_2: 0
```

I don't understand why.

But this does not happen in all versions.
In 4.1 and 5.0 getChildCount() returns 0 when i rotate the screen
In 4.2 and 4.4 works fine. getChildCount() returns 7 when I rotate the screen.

logcat:

```
    01-10 04:43:34.716: E/AndroidRuntime(1962): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-10 04:43:34.716: E/AndroidRuntime(1962): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{uva.asimov.findyourmall/uva.asimov.findyourmall.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-10 04:43:34.716: E/AndroidRuntime(1962):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
01-10 04:43:34.716: E/AndroidRuntime(1962):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
01-10 04:43:34.716: E/AndroidRuntime(1962):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3512)
01-10 04:43:34.716: E/AndroidRuntime(1962):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:130)
01-10 04:43:34.716: E/AndroidRuntime(1962):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1201)
01-10 04:43:34.716: E/AndroidRuntime(1962):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-10 04:43:34.716: E/AndroidRuntime(1962):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-10 04:43:34.716: E/AndroidRuntime(1962):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
01-10 04:43:34.716: E/AndroidRuntime(1962):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-10 04:43:34.716: E/AndroidRuntime(1962):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-10 04:43:34.716: E/AndroidRuntime(1962):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
01-10 04:43:34.716: E/AndroidRuntime(1962):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
01-10 04:43:34.716: E/AndroidRuntime(1962):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-10 04:43:34.716: E/AndroidRuntime(1962): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-10 04:43:34.716: E/AndroidRuntime(1962):     at uva.asimov.findyourmall.MainActivity.onPrepareOptionsMenu(MainActivity.java:204)
01-10 04:43:34.716: E/AndroidRuntime(1962):     at android.app.Activity.onPreparePanel(Activity.java:2494)
01-10 04:43:34.716: E/AndroidRuntime(1962):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.preparePanel(PhoneWindow.java:421)
01-10 04:43:34.716: E/AndroidRuntime(1962):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.invalidatePanelMenu(PhoneWindow.java:747)
01-10 04:43:34.716: E/AndroidRuntime(1962):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.restorePanelState(PhoneWindow.java:1677)
01-10 04:43:34.716: E/AndroidRuntime(1962):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.restoreHierarchyState(PhoneWindow.java:1627)
01-10 04:43:34.716: E/AndroidRuntime(1962):     at android.app.Activity.onRestoreInstanceState(Activity.java:928)
01-10 04:43:34.716: E/AndroidRuntime(1962):     at android.app.Activity.performRestoreInstanceState(Activity.java:900)
01-10 04:43:34.716: E/AndroidRuntime(1962):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnRestoreInstanceState(Instrumentation.java:1130)
01-10 04:43:34.716: E/AndroidRuntime(1962):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2037)
01-10 04:43:34.716: E/AndroidRuntime(1962):     ... 12 more
```

line 204:

```
((TextView) mDrawerList.getChildAt(0).findViewById(R.id.title)).setTextColor(this.getResources().getColor(R.color.list_item_title_unselected));
```

getChildAt(0) return null, and crash.

Any Solution?

Comment: try using `getCount()`

Comment: `getCountChild()` is not the problem. I have a problem when I call `getChildAt(0);` returns null, And I need the View at position 0

Comment: `getChilsCount()` help me to see why `getChildAt(0)` returns null

Comment: Because of view recycling, listView.getChildAt() will only return a view for the positions it is displaying

Comment: the listview is a navigation drawer with 7 items, and all ever are visible. I think it should'nt be a problem.

Comment: @Rohit5k2 I try `getCount()` and it returns 7, but getChildAt(0) returns null. I want the View at first position, but listView haven't any view

Comment: Does it display anything in the navigation drawer?

Comment: The activity is recreating, and stop before see nothing. In the first creation of the activity it works.

Comment: Stop?? Do you mean crash? If so please post your logcat error trace

Comment: Yes, crash. Excuse me english

Comment: Can you post your logcat error trace?

Comment: Posted. this happens when roted phone.

Comment: Can you try my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `getChildAt()` try using this

```
public View getViewByPosition(int pos, ListView listView) {
    final int firstListItemPosition = listView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
    final int lastListItemPosition = firstListItemPosition + listView.getChildCount() - 1;

    if (pos < firstListItemPosition || pos > lastListItemPosition ) {
        return listView.getAdapter().getView(pos, null, listView);
    } /*else {
        final int childIndex = pos - firstListItemPosition;
        return listView.getChildAt(childIndex);
    }*/ // Try with else part un-commented too
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Yes!!! This works. A lot of thanks! I have to try in a real device, but in emulator now work.

Comment: Ok, I will try whit new edit (part now commented), but with that part un-commented it works.

Comment: without else crash on launch

Answer (score 0):

getChildCount does not return the number of items in the listview.  It returns the number of row views in the listView.  It is 0 in onCreate because it hasn't generated those children-  it won't until it needs to draw.

When you rotate the screen, unless you have it turned off you go through Activity recreation.  So it will go back to 0, as the activity will be destroyed and recreated.  It will then go back to a non-zero number when it redraws.

Comment: the problem is getChildAt(0) returns null because ListView haven't child. And yes, when i rotate the screen, Activity is destroyed an created again. And listView is created again too. Like when I launch the app first time. but in this case the app throw FC only in android 4.1 and 5.0. In android 4.4 and 4.2 this work fine